# Limit on no of rows in sql table

Tags: php, sql, database

I have around 100000 rows in one of the tables in my database. I'm able to fetch the result easily,but when I increase the rows above 200000, at that time it does not return me anything. Help me out in this guys. What do I need to change in my table as I have to increase my rows in future as well.

There are 5 int types and 13 varchar datatype columns in that table.

Table layout is as follows.

```
Create table feed(
PID int not null,
Percentdisc int not null,
name varchar(100) not null,
brand varchar(30) not null,
store varchar(30) not null,
price int not null,
category varchar(20) not null,
url1 varchar(300) not null,
emavail varchar(100) not null,
dtime varchar(100) not null,
stock varchar(30) not null,
description varchar(200) not null,
avail varchar(20) not null,
tags varchar(30) not null,
dprice int not null,
url2 varchar(300),
url3 varchar(300),
sid int primary key auto_increment);
```

Select query which i m using

```
select * from feed where (NAME like '%Baby%' or NAME like '%Bassinet%')
```

Comment: the structure of the table is irrelevant - you should be able to store as many rows as you want. your query is probably just highly inefficient and unable to handle how you're trying to fetch your records. That means you need to show the actual `select` that "isn't working".

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server related? What query are you running?

Comment: What query are you running on the table? Is it simply taking a long time to run, or does it finish quickly and not return anything? A table structure doesn't give us anything to go off of.

Comment: Please post the query and indexes you have on the table

Comment: I have pasted the query sir.basically its quickly finishing and not returning me anything

Comment: If your column is `name`, then put that, literally, in your query. Mashing up the case is bad form. Tradition has it that SQL keywords are generally all-caps, with table and column names lower or mixed case.

Comment: What's the size of the result set?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** The query might give you an error like this - `Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php`, since the query is comsuming too much of server memory.

Try adding the below code on the top of your script -

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

It will take unlimited memory usage of server, it's working fine.

**2)** Working with too much of data, you have to use `MySQL Cursors` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

**3)** Or try using `unbuffered queries` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php

Comment: i added this and it worked@Parag.But my worry is my tables rows will be increasing upto 10lakhs or more.will it hamper me in future